# Derivative of exponential of a matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

I want to find the derivative of $$x=\exp{At}$$ with respect to $A$. In this case $A$ is a matrix. Is the solution $$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dA}=t\cdot \exp{At}$$ Or is it different?

Comment: I suspect this is only true when $A$ commutes with all matrices, because then $\exp((A+H)t)=\exp(A)(I_n+tH+O(H^2))$. If this is not the case, $\exp((A+H)t)=\exp(tA)+tH+t^2/2(AH+HA)+t^3/6(A^2H+AHA+HA^2)+\cdots +O(H^2)$.

Comment: What do you mean by ${d\over dA}$ when $A$ is a matrix variable?